# why do I need to specify a variable name for a Canvas Image Object to apper in Tkinter

Tags: python, class, user-interface, tkinter

I created a custom canvas image object class of tkinter. But when I make a instance of it it does not appear in the canvas.

Here is a simple class to create a Image Object

```py
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class CreateImage():
    def __init__(self, canvas, image_path, pos=(300, 300)):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.image_pos = pos
        self.image = Image.open(image_path)
        self.photoimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
        self.image_obj = self.canvas.create_image((self.image_pos[0], self.image_pos[1]), image=self.photoimage)
```

If I don't mention a variable name for the instance of CreateImage it won't display

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    path = 'original.jpg'
    root.geometry('600x600')
    cvs = tk.Canvas(root, background="bisque")
    cvs.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    CreateImage(cvs, path)
    root.mainloop()
```

But if I write it like `img1 = CreateImage(cvs, path)` it works.

Comment: If you no longer have a reference to the image, it gets garbage-collected - same as any other object in Python.  Unfortunately, the reference that the Canvas has to the image is entirely outside of Python, so Python has no way of taking it into account.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot for explaining! I was confused at first because I could directly create widgets such as tk.Button() then I realized that it gets associated with root, so Tkinter probably keeps a reference of it internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont need to do that if you use a slighty modified `CreateImage():` :

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class CreateImage():
    
    registry = {}
    
    def __init__(self, canvas, image_path, pos=(300, 300)):
        
        self.registry[image_path] = self
        
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.image_pos = pos
        self.image = Image.open(image_path)
        self.photoimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
        self.image_obj = self.canvas.create_image((self.image_pos[0], self.image_pos[1]), image=self.photoimage)
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    path = 'original.jpg'
    root.geometry('600x600')
    cvs = tk.Canvas(root, background="bisque")
    cvs.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    
    
    CreateImage(cvs, path)
    
    # img1 = CreateImage(cvs, path)
    
    root.mainloop()
```

See [How to reference an existing class object with no defined variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35386926/how-to-reference-an-existing-class-object-with-no-defined-variable)

Comment: ahh interesting, never though of using class variables like that. thanks!

Comment: me neither, never used them like that. I know that you use such thing to keep tracks of objects in OOP though see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12101958/how-to-keep-track-of-class-instances

Comment: dont know why it was accepted think @jasonhharper is more knowledgeadbled stating : "If you no longer have a reference to the image, it gets garbage-collected - same as any other object in Python. Unfortunately, the reference that the Canvas has to the image is entirely outside of Python, so Python has no way of taking it into account. – " my example was just another way of referencinf it and shedding light to other options in Python Object Oriented Programming ( I am trying to learn it so mthats why my effort )

Comment: jasonhharper's comment helped me understand why it was not working and answered my initial question. And pippo's answer fit what I need for my current project so I marked it as accepted. (also because it was the only answer I had)